# How to persist selection of foreign key in related table

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc-4, database-design

I have a database design that I need to get some help with

Suppose I have three tables, namely preferences, books, genres. The tables are related as follows:

[image: Database diagram]

The following tables are accessible in a view, in which the user is allowed to add a book to his personal page.

Currently, the view dictates that the user first choose a genre, before he gets the opportunity to select a book (A basic filter).

However, imagine that the user has selected a genre and decides to come back to select a book at a later point - Then this architecture doesn't support that the selected genre is saved as a part of the preferences. Meaning that, even though the user saved his preferences with a genre, he will have to, once he gets back to add his book, select the genre again in order to then select the book.

Therefore, how would I optimally "refactor" this architecture in order to support what I want to achieve.

My first intuition would be to add one more column to the preferences table named "genres_Id" and have a foreign key pointing to the genres table. I guess this is not good practice though..

Comment: Those are just different models that store different facts.  If it's important to record the user's selection of a genre, then the model should support that.

Comment: But how would I optimally support that? I mean, as I stated in my question, I could just have another foreign key in the preferences table to the genres, but that will bring other issues.

Comment: dupe of https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/264075/how-to-persist-selection-of-foreign-key-in-related-table